# Using powershell + regex to tidy file names

Tags: powershell, regex

I have a hard drive containing files with names that have been formatted by the "File History" feature of windows. A typical file name looks like this:

```
Randomfile - blah (2015_05_29 14_56_40 UTC).docx
```

or

```
1415374402647_res_original (2015_05_31 15_33_12 UTC).jpg
```

What I need to do, is remove the date/time stamp that is present at the end of each file. There are too many files to do it manually and that's why I wish to use powershell and regex to do this for me. It also needs to be recursive so it will search sub folders too.

My OS is Win7 Ultimate.

Comment: You could certainly do that in PowerShell, but I think it would be easier to use a renaming tool. There are many of them out there. I like [AdvancedRenamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Well if all you want to do is delete everything in the last set of brackets (I'm assuming all dates are in brackets):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $file = $_.FullName.Substring(0, $_.FullName.LastIndexOf("(")).Trim()
    $file + $_.FullName.Substring($_.FullName.IndexOf(")") + 1)
}
```